# Workmnager not repeating when app is cleared from recent

Tags: android, android-workmanager, periodic-task

My app was working fine then it stopped working with no reason. I used this code to let my app run some code in background(even if app is killed) but it stopped working few days ago. I don't know why it's not working anymore. I didn't change anything there.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicSyncDataWork =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES ).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "NOTIFICATION_WORKER",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, //Existing Periodic Work policy
                periodicSyncDataWork //work request
        );
```

If i test on emulator (Android 8.1) it works fine but when i test on real device (tested on Android 8.1 and Android 10), it works only when my app is active or in background (no more working when app is killed). I can't figure out why this behaviour

Comment: On which device are you seeing this behavior?  
Some launchers do a force stop of the application when it is "swiped-out". This is seen by the OS as the user-request to "turn-off" that application and all the Job scheduled by WorkManager in the underlying JobScheduler are cancelled.

Comment: @pfmaggi Have you got any solution?, please help me on it

Comment: In fact this was an issue only on chinese ROMs. Disable app from battery savers (Generally more than one ) and momery optimzer. Solved the issue for me